Exclude almost all nested submodules from one submodule
I've found this 5 year old answer that almost answers my question, but not quite.
My git repo contains several submodules, many of which contain submodules themselves.
I want to be able to run git submodule update --init --recursive to easily initialize the entire environment.
The downside is that boost is in there somewhere, which has 150+ submodules itself, of which I only need 2.
I can't for the life of me figure out how to exclude submodules from a single nested submodule.
When I run git -c submodule."lib/boost".update=none submodule update --init --recursive it just skips boost, but I don't want to skip boost: I want to init/clone/pull boost and two of its submodules (container and lockfree)
I can't omit --recursive because then I'd have to explicitly add all of the other submodules, which are a lot.

What's wrong with doing that, skipping boost for the initial recursive init and then doing boost's init retail? That's what you want, recursive except for boost where you only want that one plus two selected from its submodules.

What I want, is to only have to run one command that initializes my git repo the way I want it. What I don't want, is to have to run multiple commands. I just assumed that there's a way I can place some magical file somwhere that tells git to exclude some stuff.

That magical file somewhere would be your setup script.

"Write a script" is always an answer. It's a very last resport in my situation. Hence the StackOverflow question.

I'm having a hard time imagining what would be clearer or simpler than a file with the four commands that already do exactly what you want.

If you gonna run git submodule update --init --recursive just once there is no simple way to exclude most but not all submodules of Boost. The closest solution is to skip Boost completely and then update 2 submodules manually. If you gonna run git submodule update --init --recursive regularly then you can configure most submodules of Boost to be ignored and allow to only update the two you're interested in.
